# Balance overflow - ethereum sample token

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens, overflow

[Here](https://ethereum.org/token) is the first example token.

> ```
> pragma solidity ^0.4.20;
>
> contract MyToken {
>     /* This creates an array with all balances */
>     mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
>
>     /* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract */
>     function MyToken(
>         uint256 initialSupply
>         ) public {
>         balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply;              // Give the creator all initial tokens
>     }
>
>     /* Send coins */
>     function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public {
>         require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);           // Check if the sender has enough
>         require(balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]); // Check for overflows
>         balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;                    // Subtract from the sender
>         balanceOf[_to] += _value;                           // Add the same to the recipient
>     }
> }
> ```

I don't understand this line code:

```
require(balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]);
```

Because `_value` is an unint, why do we need to check if the final amount of recipient is greater than or equal to the previous amount? I see that this line of code always returns true, I do believe I miss something here. If you know why we need to check this, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I see that this line of code always returns true

No, This is true unless it [overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow). When unit overflow happens that's  false. Here the unit used unit256 will have a max value of 2**256-1.

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/aquabu/30378c5375f388a28572dd18d58f787f) shows example of unit overflow and underflow.

> ```
> /* demonstrating uint overflow and underflow in ethereum solidity
>    this is why you need guards like: 
>      if (balances[_to] + _amount < balances[_to]) throw; 
> */ 
> contract C {
>     // (2**256 - 1) + 1 = 0
>     function overflow() returns (uint256 _overflow) {
>         uint256 max = 2**256 - 1;
>         return max + 1;
>     }
>
>     // 0 - 1 = 2**256 - 1
>     function underflow() returns (uint256 _underflow) {
>         uint256 min = 0;
>         return min - 1;
>     }
> }
> ```

So this check is required.